# Image editing Paid API for iOS

Tags: ios4

I am working on iPhone application in which I need to implement editing image properties.
If user select an image, can able to change brightness, contrast, saturation, etc and can write some text in image background/foreground.
I any one worked on this type please give reference or sample code.
or any free or paid  API for this
will help me a lot

Ex:http://www.wordfoto.com/

Thanks,
Aaryan

Answer (score 1):

I used Apple's [GLImageProcessing example project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html) to add image filtering capabilities to one of my apps.

The project contains Brightness, Contrast, Saturation, Hue rotation and Sharpness image filters. The issue is that the project is using the opengl framework. Not so simple to modify and tweak if you never using opengl before